# How to avoid strange characters before the request in firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, httpresponse

on a website i'm currently developing I'm using jquery to do all sort of magic things :-)
In firefox however, when I load jquery 1.4.2 there are sometimes funny characters in front of the request.

You can see the strangers characters in this screenshot (thank you firebug). [alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3357132/Screen%20shot%202010-06-07%20at%2015.15.29.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3357132/Screen%20shot%202010-06-07%20at%2015.15.29.jpg)

In safari, Chrome and IE these funny characters don't appear, jquery is loading fine in those browsers.

Why are those characters appearing and how can I remove them?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it possible it's getting double gzipped from the server?

Comment: Turning off the content compression (gzip) on the server solved the problem indeed. I'll contact our server-people to ask for more info! Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off the content compression (gzip) on the server solved the problem.