# jquery.ajax returns content-type "html" on iis while it returns content-type "json" on local host

Tags: jquery

I am using `jQuery.ajax` function to make an ajax call to a page method in asp.net. I specifically set the `content-type` to `application/json; charset=utf-8`. When I looked at the response in the firebug it says the content-type is html.

The following is the code to my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
            async: asyncVal,
            type: "POST",
            url: url + '/' + webMethod, 
            data: dataPackage,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",            
            error: errorFunction,
            success: successFunction
        });
```

Comment: Is the server code you're running on localhost the same as what is on IIS? Is it a web server, WCF, an aspx page?

Comment: Could you post the server part code.

Answer (score 1):

You request a certain content type, but if your script does not handle this request by setting the response headers accordingly, you let IIS decide what to return. Just force the header to the right value.

Comment: how would I do that? The page methods are in asp.net page.

Comment: I don't know asp at all but in symfony php framework, you would do this : $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
Search for something similar...

Comment: when I look at the firebug, it gives the content type as "application/json" now. but the data I am getting back is not "json". It is sending some funky characters.

Comment: Like in this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989848/how-to-avoid-strange-characters-before-the-request-in-firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

I am missing the "ScriptModule" tag in the web.config on the server. After I added that tag everything worked fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory"
                 verb="*" path="*.asmx"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                 resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```